# How to Make Rest Call from Cisco Unified CCX editor

Tags: cisco

The Problem is im trying to enter URL in properties of Make Rest Call but every time I enter something it shows this error

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, basically the problem was when I removed the https:// from my URL it allowed me to type URL and other information.